# Let $Tf(x)=\int_{[0,x]}fdm$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$. Prove that $C_0((0,1])=\{f \in C[0,1] : f(0)=0\}$ is a closed subspace of $C[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $Tf(x)=\int_{[0,x]}fdm$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$.

Prove that $C_0((0,1])=\{f \in C[0,1] : f(0)=0\}$ is a closed subspace of $C[0,1]$

---

I need a bit of help with this one. I was thinking of proving that the complement is open, or maybe showing that given any convergent sequence in $C_0((0,1])$ its limit has to be in $C_0((0,1])$.... Could use some help though!! THanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that a linear subspace of $C([0,1])$ is closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2034747/prove-that-a-linear-subspace-of-c0-1-is-closed)

Comment: What does $T$ have to do with the problem?

Comment: You don't specify a topology on $C([0,1])$ so we cannot tell.